# Cross-browser linear gradient

Tags: css, cross-browser, linear-gradients

What will be the cross-browser CSS for the following linear-gradient style ?

```css
background: linear-gradient(bottom, #E4E8EA 0%, #E8EBED 50%, #f1f3f4 96.36%, #fff 100%);
```

Comment: Why do you have two linear gradients if neither of them are transparent? (They’re also exactly the same.) Also, it’s not possible to specify stops in a gradient in IE9 or earlier. Apart from that, throw all the prefixes on it, except for `-ms-`. And finally, if it’s so crucial that it needs to support IE8, you are doing design wrong.

Comment: It can be solved for most IE-versions using a filter. You can check http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ for samples.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren: Does a filter support colour stops?

Comment: Not sure about that, I prefer not to render the gradients at all in IE.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
-moz-linear-gradient() /*mozilla*/
```

or

```
-webkit-linear-gradient() /*safari,chrome*/
```

or

```
-ms-linear-gradient() /*IE*/
```

or

```
-o-linear-gradient() /*opera*/
```

alongside in your style

Comment: What about Opera? What about IE?